# How to call a View Controller from not related View Controller programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, segue

as you see on the image, on the normal case I click the button1 to call the second view and then I click the button2 to call the last view, and in a particular scenario I want to click the button1 to call the last view. 
I added this on the methode viewDidLoad:

```
if(condition)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"thirdview" sender:self];
```

but it is not working, any help please.

thank you.[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a segue from `ViewController1` to `Viewcontroller3`.

But if you do this with many viewControllers then it becomes messy, I call it the spaguetti segues.

The alternative is to present that `viewController` modally.

Example:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
ViewController3 *viewController = 
        [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

(make sure you give ViewController3 a `storyboardId`)

Comment: I agree with this answer. Loading the view by storyboard id is a clean way to handle this unique case. I don't think a ui element can have more than one segue attached to it.